# In vs Into (differences in a particular context)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, difference

Look at this meaning of against: *"`In` or `into` physical contact with (something), so as to be supported by or collide with it"*.

1.What is the difference between *in* and *into* here?

2.Could you contrast both in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***in*** situates in space

> The cupboard leans against the wall (is ***in*** contact with the wall so as to be supported by it)

***into*** both situates in space AND shows direction (so it will be used with verbs of movement):

> The waves rushed against the rocks (came ***into*** contact with the rocks so as to collide with them).